# Thinkpad T400 visual artifacting in Windows - stops when the graphics 'refresh'

Tags: windows, display, thinkpad, vram

I have a T400 which runs Windows 10, build 1903. A lot of the time there is artifacting or random lines or squares glitched on the screen, and when i move my mouse over it it fixes, which makes me believe its a VRAM issue or something. After a lot of graphics change (like opening Chrome) then more artifacting appears all at once until I move my mouse to fix it.

The problem persists when I use the VGA port and an external monitor - when duplicating the screen I can see the artifacting on the external monitor too.

I booted into Linux Mint 19.3 for a bit (with and without the external monitor) and didn't see any corruption, but in any case i'd like to know if its a hardware or software issue, and if anyone has had this issue before.

[image]

Many thanks

EDIT: To anyone who comes across this, I did not solve the issue, and ended up using Linux Mint 19.3 all the time as this doesn't occur on Linux. I suggest you use some flavor/distribution of Linux instead of using an earlier, supported Windows (assuming its a windows graphic driver issue and not  hardware related) simply due to security vulnerabilities.

Comment: There are multiple versions of Windows 10.  Are you running 1909 or 2004?  Please edit your question to include this information. What version you are running is vital, there was substantial changes to WDDM and your hardware might not be compatible with it.

Comment: @Ramhound Ah, sure, sorry. I'm running Windows 10 1903 (not latest, sorry); I've have updated the post